Как узнать что пишет пользователь после введённой команды?Библиотека discord.py
Примерно должно выглядеть так:
/say ("сообщение") 

и вот мне как раз надо узнать это сообщение

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

может поможет https://stackoverflow.com/q/61313756/13754729

https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/slash-commands.md#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8
